# How do I have a vue component be both draggable and present a hover menu?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop, vue-component, vuetify.js

I've created a custom Vue component (intended to be used in lists, tables, etc -- so multiple renderings) that I want to be able to drag-and drop.

```
<my-component v-for="item in items" :key="item.id 
  :item="item" 
  @dragstart="pickup(item.id)"
  @dragover.prevent
  @dragenter.prevent
/>
```

The component actually looks like this:

```
<template>
  <v-chip variant="outlined" draggable
    :id="`draggable-chip-${item.id}`"
    :append-icon="item.icon"
  >{{ item.title }}
  </v-chip>
  <v-menu :activator="`#draggable-chip-${item.id}`" open-on-hover location="end center">
    <!-- the menu view -- content isn't important now -->
  </v-menu>
</template>
```

The menu appears correctly, but there's a problem. Without the menu, it works fine, but when I put the menu in, the `pickup` function doesn't get called.

If I put the menu *inside* the `v-chip` and use the `parent` activator slot, both the menu and the function appear, but with two issues:

1. The menu appears when the cursor is dragged only over the chip text, not the icon or the margin areas on either side of them.
2. Likely for the same reason, the menu actually appears to the right of the text, covering up the append icon.

How do I get what I want--the menu appearing outside the v-chip, while dragging still propagates up the hierarchy to call the pickup function?